# upload file works fine on localhost but work on notserver

Tags: php, html

I have some code on localhost, and they work fine, but when I put them(html, php) on live server, it stack in the first upload part,
on the php side:

```
$target_dir = "wwwroot/aaa/html/temp/";
$target_file = $target_dir . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    $exist =  "file has already been uploaded.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if ($uploadOk == 0) {

} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {
        $test="uploaded";
    } else {
        $fail="fail uploaded";
    }
    }
$tempfilename=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
$array=array("$tempfilename","$fail");
echo json_encode($array);
```

On html side:

```
<input type="file" id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload"></input>




 $.ajax({
            url: 'loadfile.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (html) {
                loadfileName=html[0];
                alert(html[0]+' '+html[1]);
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
```

Alert is always "/temp/someRandomCharacters"+"fail uploaded", but that works fine on localhost. Any help appreciated.

Comment: often this is permission issue with the target directory

Comment: So, have you looked at the error log on the server to see what the issue is? Because that is the first thing you should always do.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Yes, "The server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)"

Comment: The server response code != the error log. The error log is actually a file that exists on the server that php writes to with a message specifically saying why something failed. If it was a permission issue, it would say something like `Failed to move file on line XX of loadfile.php: Permission denied`

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I see.. could you tell me that what does  "The server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)  http://wwwroot/aaa/html/temp/ "means?

Comment: The 403 Forbidden error could be from several things. Most HTTP status codes are pretty generic. The most common cause of a 403 that I know of would be that apache (or whatever the webserver is) doesn't have read permissions on the script and so can't read the script to execute it. That would be loadfile.php should be something like 644 permissions meaning that anyone can read it, but only the owner (should be you) can write to it.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, you aren't doing any sort of validation on your upload. So just please don't make something like this public. As it stands, i could upload a php script and run it just like any other script there. I would have full access to your entire server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder you are uploading to needs to have permissions set to 775

Comment: Thanks, never thinking of permissions problem